# mongodb: how to compare String from document to the String constructed by expression in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a trouble with creating a view in MongoDB. I'm just starting with Mongo, so the question could look pretty silly.

I have the following document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(12213054), 
    ... 
    "_dt" : {
        "_doc" : "time", 
        "time" : "01:30", 
        "date" : "04/02/18", 
        "tz" : "CET", 
        "tzoffset" : NumberInt(3600), 
        "uts" : NumberInt(1517704200)
    }, 
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to create a view for documents that have a date '04/02/18'.
The type of `"_dt.date"` field is `String`. And I'm trying to compare it using `$eq` operator.

I have the following query to select the data:

```
{$match: {
    "_dt.date": {
        $eq: { 
            $concat: [  
                {$dateToString: {
                    format: "%d/%m/",
                    date: new Date("2018-02-04")
                }},
                {$substr: [
                    {$year : new Date("2018-02-04")},
                    2,
                    2
                ]}
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

But after I execute the query the result is empty.

The date string constructed by the subquery seems to be correct:

```
db.matches.aggregate({ $project: { date:
{ 
            $concat: [
                {$dateToString: {
                    format: "%d/%m/",
                    date: new Date("2018-02-04")
                }},
                {$substr: [
                    {$year : new Date("2018-02-08")},
                    2,
                    2
                ]}
            ]
        }
}
}
)
```

Output is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(12213054), 
    "date" : "04/02/18"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the first query doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$match` by design compares a field against a constant value with regular query operators.

For comparing two fields in mongodb you've to use `$match` with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) with aggregation query operators in 3.6.

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

```
{"$match":{
  "$expr":{
    "$eq":[
      "$_dt.date", 
      {"$concat":[
        {"$dateToString":{"format":"%d/%m/","date":new Date("2018-02-04")}},
        {"$substr":[{"$year":new Date("2018-02-04")},2,2]}
      ]}
  }
}}
```

Or

You can simply pass the date string created on client side and compare directly

```
{"$match":{"_dt.date":"04/02/18"}}
```

Comment: That's the thing, that I need to use the Date() to be able to select the documents with the current date. So the {"$match":{"_dt.date":"04/02/18"}} will not work. But $expr works well! Thank you!